# Spatial Analyst Cell Statistics tool in Python gives inaccurate results

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst

My question is similar to the [Cell Statistics gives Wrong Answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8780/spatial-analyst-cell-statistics-seems-to-give-the-wrong-answer-in-arcgis-10-0) question. In Python, I'm using the MINIMUM parameter to execute the cell statistics tool on several reclassified rasters ('0's and '1's) and I'm not getting accurate results.  However, when I use the tool in ArcMap I get what I'm looking for.  It seems as if it's only using two rasters (don't know which ones).  Here's the code I'm using.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = ("F:\\hdf\\hdf_test\\reclass")
outh10v03 = ("F:\\hdf\\hdf_test\\h10v03\\")

h10v03 = arcpy.ListRasters("*2000*h10v03*", "tif")

for reclass in h10v03:
    print reclass

arcpy.gp.CellStatistics_sa(h10v03, outh10v03 + "h10v03_2000" + ".tif", "MINIMUM", "DATA")
```

Any ideas as to why it's not using all rasters (I believe that's the case)?

Comment: Can you format your code using the `{}` button? At the moment, there is no indentation in your `for` loop. I don't know if that is due to formatting or your code.

Comment: Is the Cell Statistics function on the full list? i.e `h10v03`? If that's the case, changing the Cell Stats argument might help. Also, when I formatted the code I assumed the call was outside the loop - just cofirming.

Comment: Thanks for editing the code, I'm still learning how format code on this site.  By the full list do you mean are all the rasters that have the strings "2000" and "h10v03" in the file name being used in the tool? I believe so as the print reclass statement prints out all the files that need to be used in the tool.  Also, I'm not indenting the for loop (using the ESRI format) and I tried calling the tool inside and outside of the loop, but I get the same results.

Comment: No worries. In this case I think it may be a case of putting the wrong variable inside the Cell Stats argument. Try using `arcpy.gp.CellStatistics_sa(h10v03, outh10v03 + "h10v03_2000" + ".tif", "MINIMUM", "DATA")` outside the for loop instead. If it's stil not working then we can try a different tack.

Comment: No luck, I tried using the tool outside the for loop.  My first thought is that it has to do with the [Listing Data](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z00000011000000) method and how it behaves when it's called by the tool.

Comment: As @om_henners notes above in his bit of code, it looks like your code is using the variable `reclass` which, by the time it loops through your raster list, will be only the last raster. Make sure you're using the full list variable `h10v03`.

Comment: Excellent! That worked. Can someone explain to me why the variable `reclass` in the `for` loop is the incorrect way of using a list of variables in an ArcGIS tool. @Jason hinted that this way of using a list of variables will lead to only 1 dataset (the last one in the loop) being used in the tool.

Comment: Glad it worked! When you execute a `for` loop on a list you designate a variable to hold each item in the list so that you can do some process on it. In your case you are using a variable called `reclass` to hold each of the raster name strings in your raster list and then print it to the screen. Once the `for` loop is finished the variable still exists and is equal to the last value in the list that you looped through. Read [this](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) reference article on using `for` loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain if the problem is due to indentation in your code, or whether it is due to formatting on the site:

```
for reclass in h10v03:
    print reclass

arcpy.gp.CellStatistics_sa(reclass, outh10v03 + "h10v03_2000" + ".tif", "MINIMUM", "DATA") 
# only the last line is run once
```

In this case it should loop through all of the tifs in the folder:

```
for reclass in h10v03:
    print reclass    
    arcpy.gp.CellStatistics_sa(reclass, outh10v03 + "h10v03_2000" + ".tif", "MINIMUM", "DATA")
    # here the line arcpy.gp.CellStatistics_sa ... is run for every raster in h10v03
```

Comment: You are correct in that `arcpy.gp.Cellstatistics_sa(reclass, outh10v03 + "h10v03_2000" + ".tif", "MINIMUM", "DATA") should be within the `for` loop. However, I was using the wrong list variable. the appropriate variable (the use of all rasters in the list) was `h10v03` and not `reclass`. Thanks for your response.